# I Moved my Joomla site but now I can't login to admin tools

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

We recently had to move one of our client's websites to a new server (unix to unix).  They have a Joomla site.  I followed Joomla's documentation on transferring the whole site, and did so with no problems.  I downloaded all the files via FTP, I exported the database in phpMyAdmin.  I uploaded all the files to the new server via FTP, and imported the database sql file into the new database with phpMyAdmin.

When I access the site, all the pages are there, all content is working exactly as it used to.  The site was successfully moved.

However, now when logging in as admin to add new pages or edit current ones, it will not let us log in and says that the user name and password do not match.  It's the exact same log in credentials used on the previous server and they worked there.

Any help in understanding what's going wrong?  If you need me give more info, please ask and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with logging in could be caused by few things.

- Bad admin password, so change it in `#_users` -> http://stepolabs.com/upload/pass.png
- Problems with CHMOD, put administrator folders -r to 755
- Problem with cookies, so delete it with cache in browser and on server.
- If nothing above helps, read this article: http://kb.siteground.com/i_cant_log_into_the_joomla_backend_as_administrator/

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was in the first bullet you provided.  I just created a new Super Administrator in the table and was able to login using that!

Answer (score 0):

1. Got to a md5 converter website, choose a new password, convert it to md5.
2. Log in to phpMyAdmin or whatever tool are you using to manipulate the database.
3. Open the _users table, search for your user.
4. Edit your user, change the password field to your new md5 encoded password and save

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of solution (joomla 2.5) and none of them worked... I've been able to login on the backend when I changed in configuration.php

```
    public $session_handler = 'database';
```

to

```
    public $session_handler = 'none';
```

I also removed the domain name in the variable public $cookie_domain = '';

If ever this help anyone else :)